# How to pass custom layout listviews onitemclick event to its parent activity?

Tags: android, listview

My activity loads listview from customListLayout.java (`BaseAdapter`) file, where I have written custom list and its click event, using customAdapter.java class.

Also in my activity I have `onTouchListener (onClickListener)`, now I want to pass `onItemClick` event to the parent activity.

I tried writing `onTouch` and `onClick` events on customList and returned false, but event is not passed to the main activity.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a seperate class for adapter, try passing a handler to the constructor of adapter class and use it to send message to parent activity.

```
    public CustomAdapter(context context, Handler h) {
        this.handler = h;
    }
```

Later you can use handler to pass events to your parent activity.